# Django - Creating Objects for models and saving it to MYSQL

Tags: python, django

I  have designed an sample registration form and was using it save it to database . I can successfully save an entry to database but the problem is when create an second entry it overrides the first entry

register.html

```
<form action="/register_process/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="unamefield">Enter Username</label>
<input type="text" name="unamefield">
<label for="unamefield">Enter Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pwdfield">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class UserRegistration(models.Model):
    USER_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    USER_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PASSWORD = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'USER'
```

## views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)


def register_process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        uname = request.POST.get('unamefield')
        pwd = request.POST.get('pwdfield')
        obj_userregistration = UserRegistration(USER_NAME=uname, PASSWORD=pwd)
        obj_userregistration.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('<html>Success</html>')
```

Comment: What do you mean overrides? Did you make a SELECT from database to see what it has?

Comment: yea i used SELECT * FROM MYSITE.USER; The previously created entry in overwritten by the current entry

Answer (score 1):

You've made a few errors in defining your model.

First, there is no reason to define your fields IN UPPER CASE. That's very strange.

More importantly, you have defined a USER_ID field as a charfield and set it to be the primary key. But you have not provided any way to actually generate a new value for this field. Unless you have a *really* good reason, you should not define a manual PK field at all, but let Django add an autoincremented integer field automatically.

But even more importantly than this, **you should on no account do what you have done here at all**. You are storing your passwords in clear text in the database, opening yourself to all sorts of hacking. Do not ever do this. Django includes a whole authentication framework where this is done properly, and there is absolutely no reason for you to bypass this as you have done. Do not do it.

Comment: Okay . I am just practicing Django . I am an beginner so very confused where to start and go . Thanks i will follow your steps